# Senstivity analysis error in Python using SALib

Tags: python-3.x

following [Performing a sensitivity analysis with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045699/performing-a-sensitivity-analysis-with-python) I receive an error.

My code is as follows:

```
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol

def ls(X):
    # column 0 = demand, column 1 =  bookings, column 2 = inventory
    return max(X[:,0] - X[:,1] - X[:,2])

problem = {'num_vars': 3,
           'names': ['demand', 'bookings', 'inventory'],
           'bounds': [[0, 1250],
                     [0, 11000],
                     [0, 120000]]
           } 

# Generate samples
param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, 10000000, calc_second_order=False)

# Run model
Y = ls(param_values)

# Perform analysis
Si = sobol.analyze(problem, Y)
```

I receive the following error.
RuntimeError: 
        Incorrect number of samples in model output file.
        Confirm that calc_second_order matches option used during sampling.

When I look at https://github.com/SALib/SALib/blob/master/SALib/analyze/sobol.py 
I see:

```
if calc_second_order and Y.size % (2 * D + 2) == 0:
        N = int(Y.size / (2 * D + 2))
    elif not calc_second_order and Y.size % (D + 2) == 0:
        N = int(Y.size / (D + 2))
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("""
        Incorrect number of samples in model output file.
        Confirm that calc_second_order matches option used during 
sampling.""")
```

However, this does not really help me in solving the error. Does it have to do with the second argument in saltelli.sample()?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems. First, the function `ls()` returns a single value when it should be a vector of length equal to the number of rows in `param_values`. Second, the default assumption in `saltelli.sample()` and `sobol.analyze()` is to have `calc_second_order=True`, so you need to set it to `False` in both cases. Here is some example code that runs, but you may have to adjust the `ls()` function to meet your requirements.

```
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol

def ls(X):
    # column 0 = demand, column 1 =  bookings, column 2 = inventory
    # modified to return a vector (max was returning max value of vector)
    return (X[:,0] - X[:,1] - X[:,2])

problem = {'num_vars': 3,
           'names': ['demand', 'bookings', 'inventory'],
           'bounds': [[0, 1250],
                     [0, 11000],
                     [0, 120000]]
           } 

# Generate samples
param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, 10000000, calc_second_order=False)

# Run model
Y = ls(param_values)

# Perform analysis
Si = sobol.analyze(problem, Y,calc_second_order=False)
```