# How to run a sensitivity analyses without an equation but existing output parameters?

Tags: python, statistics

I would like to run an sensitivity analyses on some computertomography-based parameters (input) and their effect on the output parameter (local porosity [%]) in jupyter Notebook. I managed to reduce the parameter input down to 3 parameters:

(A) contrast (max value: 100 %. start value: 0 %. Intervall: 10 %)

(B) artefact-treshhold (max value: 50 voxels. start value: 5 voxels. Intervall: 5 voxels)

(C) defect-(porosity)-treshhold (max value: 80 voxels. start value: 2 voxels. Intervall: 2 voxels)

the parameter output is defined as a local porosity value [%] (max value 85 %) for each parameter combination.

(the porosity values can be randomly generated in order to check if the written code works properly)

My basic idea would be using the SAlib library from python, define the variables as well as the modell I want to check.

I already checked the forum and found this specific question:

[Performing a sensitivity analysis with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045699/performing-a-sensitivity-analysis-with-python)

the first problem is, that I do not want to perform the sensitivity analyses on an equation. I want to perform the sensitivity analyses on existing input parameters and one output parameter.

the second problem is, that my current parameter screening is probably too short resulting in some missing parameters that I have not found yet.